# Can I attach drop ceiling molding to a brick chimney?

Tags: ceiling, chimney

I have a drop ceiling in most areas of my basement. The previous owners did not complete the job over top of where the wood stove is, and around the brick chimney behind the stove. I don't think this looks nice, plus I am sure a lot of heat ends up going between the drop ceiling and the floor above, and gets trapped there.

If installed, the drop ceiling would be further than the minimum clearance to combustibles relative to the stove pipe connecting into the chimney (8" vertically above the stove pipe).

If it matters, the chimney flue has a inner SS liner, wrapped in a ceramic blanket. I am fairly sure there are concrete blocks around that, and decorative bricks around that.

Question: Is there a safety/codes reason why this job was not completed? Can I just run the track for the drop ceiling around and mounted to the brick chimney?

Only reason that I can imagine is that there is a small risk that a drop ceiling tile falls down on the operating stove...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the code question is variable according to your location, especially if you're in the US as there will be federal, state, county, and maybe even city codes with which to comply.

Besides codes there's simple common sense answers. I think I understand that the stove's pipe goes up an actual brick chimney, not just exposed through the ceiling, and my answer assumes that. I can't see any reason why you can't run the drop ceiling up to the chimney as long as you use fire-rated materials, that means the tracks, track fittings, and tiles themselves. You should make sure about that for the whole drop ceiling really.